# Quiet (unattended) install of SQL Server Express LocalDb 2019

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, sql-server-2019-express

With SQL Server Express LocalDb 2012 ([Microsoft MSI download](https://download.microsoft.com/download/8/D/D/8DD7BDBA-CEF7-4D8E-8C16-D9F69527F909/ENU/x64/SqlLocalDB.MSI)) it was possible to do an unattended install from a command line:

```
msiexec /i SqlLocalDB.msi /qn IACCEPTSQLLOCALDBLICENSETERMS=YES
```

This works pretty stable for me on various versions of MS Windows I have tested.

I cannot get it working this way with the SQL Server Express LocalDb version 2019 ([Microsoft MSI download](https://download.microsoft.com/download/7/c/1/7c14e92e-bdcb-4f89-b7cf-93543e7112d1/SqlLocalDB.msi)). The combination of switches that worked before does not work any more.

**How to install the SQL Server Express LocalDb 2019 (the particular SqlLocalDB.msi) in a quiet (unattended) mode?**

I have also tried to download the SQL Server 2019 media and call the setup.exe with switches as provided in the documentation ([MS Documentation of running setup.exe](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads)) but it does not allow me to install LocalDb neither. I have tried a few combinations of switches like the one below, and it does not work for me, the product does not get installed.

```
setup.exe /Q /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /ACTION="install" /FEATURES=LocalDb
```

I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

LocalDB is a feature of SQL Server Express, so download SQL Server Express 2019, then:

`SQL2019-SSEI-Expr.exe /Action=Download /MediaType=LocalDB /Quiet`

This saves the LocalDB installer to: `%USERPROFILE%\Downloads\en-US\SqlLocalDB.msi`

You can now install LocalDb with the basic GUI (progress bar only):

`msiexec.exe /qb /i %USERPROFILE%\Downloads\en-US\SqlLocalDB.msi IAcceptSqlLocalDBLicenseTerms=YES`

Comment: Thank you, is it possible to install the LocalDb with no GUI? no progress bar? Just fully unattended as it was possible with SQL 2012?

Comment: Sorry, @msporek, I was not able to use the `/qn` (no gui) switch successfully. The `msiexec.exe` process just seemed to hang around consuming no CPU and virtually no memory.

Answer (score 0):

I got the fully unattended (`/qn`) install working by **running the command from an elevated (Run as administrator) command prompt**.

Comment: Could you provide more details (e.g. the command line parameters you used)? I couldn't make it work either.