# Install Microsoft SQL Server localdb on client's machine through C# application

Tags: c#, sql, squirrel.windows

I have a C# WinForms application that connects to a .mdf data file which will be stored on the client's machine. I need to install Sql Server 2019 localdb on their machine but I was wondering whether there was a way in which I could do this discretely through a setup window when they run my software.

I don't want to have to go through all of their machines individually installing SQL Server as it would be an inconvenience for both myself and themselves and I want to make the setup as simple as possible for them.

Would I be able to run a command through the command prompt to install the software?

I know you can add prerequisites to the application but I am using a third-party software to publish my application (Squirrel) rather than ClickOnce.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Quiet (unattended) install of SQL Server Express LocalDb 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61360163/quiet-unattended-install-of-sql-server-express-localdb-2019) See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-from-the-command-prompt?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Side note: I'm guessing you are using `AttachDbFilename` in your app connection string, if so see [what's the issue with AttachDbFilename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178720/whats-the-issue-with-attachdbfilename)