# how to use sql server for creating window application and installing the application on other systems

Tags: sql-server, database, sqlconnection

When I create window form application it works fine but when I install on other system it shows database error. so how to develop an application where the connection string is changed by the time of installation or what type of database should be used.

I installed sql server databases, sql management studio in the target system but failed. please show me how applications are built which requires no installation of sql server etc. or a method in which confection string is changed by the time of installation.

Comment: Do you want: A. multiple people using your application to share data from _one central_ database, or B. Each application user gets their own private database?

Comment: B. Each application user gets their own database

Comment: I suggest you use LocalDB and have it install with your app https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68749827/install-microsoft-sql-server-localdb-on-clients-machine-through-c-sharp-applica